# In SharePoint 2013, how to change a broken hyperlink embedded in an InfoForm without using code?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm new to SharePoint. While completing an InfoForm, I discovered a URL designed to direct users to a publication was broken. I have the new URL but can't find the base document to install it. Any ideas on where to start? Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0):

Good day! InfoPath Forms can either be lists or in libraries.

If its in a list...

1. Navigate to the list
2. In the list ribbon above, click on LIST
3. Click on "Customize in InfoPath"

If its in a library...

1. Navigate to the library
2. In the library ribbon above, click on Library Settings.
3. Click on Advance Settings
4. Set allow management of content types to no
5. Where it says document template, click on Edit Template, that's the Infopath form.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can't customise a Document Library with InfoPath.

Answer (score 0):

If Kyle answer will not work it means you have admin approved InfoPath form that was uploaded via Central Admin to backup the the IP you can use the:

```
Export-SPInfoPathAdministrationFiles
```

Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/export-spinfopathadministrationfiles?view=sharepoint-ps